# Redirection in security.yml

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I have the FOSUserBundle installed and configured and everything works good.
But I need when user goes to / URI, symfony2 checks if the user logged in, if logged in stay on / URI and load profile page, if not redirect him to /login page.

How to do this in security.yml.

I tried this:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path: /login
                default_target_path: /
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

But it gives me: No route found for "GET /"

Comment: Have you a controller configured for this route? Please add the output of `php app/console router:debug`

Comment: I have added the controller for / route, now when I go to the / route, it redirects me to the /login page, perfect. But after log in, it redirects me to /_wdt/edc259 which is blank page instead of / and in debug panel I see "Logged in as anon".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect your page after login
**security.yml**

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                provider:             fos_userbundle
                default_target_path:  /dashboard/                
            logout:     
                ........
                invalidate_session: false
            anonymous: ~
```

**In the routing file**

```
applicationlogin_success:
  pattern: /dashboard/
  defaults: { _controller: SampleBundle:Default:FrontPage }
```

BY USING default_target_path : ROUTING_PATTERN 
u will redirect it...